# Using VBA, how do I navigate to an URL and then download a link from that URL?

Tags: vba, download, csv

I need to create a macro that imports some data from a CSV file. However, I can only access the file by running a static, non-dynamic URL *after* I have navigated to a URL that has an identifier that changes for every client.

i.e. I need to navigate to `https://fsfsf.asdfsf.com/sdfgfg/fssfs.aspx?previewaction=XXXX` and then instantiate `https://fsfsf.asdfsf.com/sdfgfg/sdfsdf/FieldAttributes`, which in a browser would cause the file to be downloaded.

Thanks!

Would I be doing this, then?

So, I'd be doing

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://secure.infosnap.com/family/gosnap.aspx?previewaction=13461"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = "https://secure.infosnap.com/family/ActionForms/FieldAttributes"

Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\file.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not answer my question as it does not address navigating to secondary URL and then performing the download.

Comment: Use `myURL` once, `Get` the object, then change `myURL` to the secondary URL and `Get` it again.

Comment: @Vegard and others, let me know if the code I've added is correct or not. It looks like it's not. Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you remove the username and password (or substitute for that which is correct)... does it work?